# Russian National with permanent Italian Residence card going to Curacao

Tags: russian-citizens

Would my Italian Residence card be sufficient for travelling to Curacao without Visa ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the permesso di soggiorno means that you do not require a visa to enter Curaçao.

Timatic, the database which airlines use to verify passenger travel documents, states:

> Visa required, except for Passengers with a residence or a re-entry permit issued by Italy.
>   Visa required, except for Passengers with a D visa issued by a
>   Schengen Member State.

You might still require a visa to transit some other country to travel to or from Curaçao, such as Canada or USA. Some airlines have direct flights to Schengen area airports though.

Comment: Here is a publicly accessible Timatic link for anyone interested: https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b
It'll give you basic info on what documents you'll need based on your origin, destination and residence.